# How to change color of the splits counter in a 'tabline'

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, tabbed-user-interface

I can have multiple splits in a new tab. To change background and foreground of active and inactive `tabpages`, I can do the following:

```
hi TabLineSel term=bold ctermfg=White ctermbg=DarkBlue
hi TabLine ctermfg=White ctermbg=Black
```

Now, if I have multiple splits in a tab, Vim shows this by a number in the `tabline`.  How do I change that number's color?

In the case of attached picture, how do I change the color of number 3, meaning I have 3 splits?

[image]

Please let me know and thank you.

Comment: By the way, why use a number to display how many splits you have open? I would say it's more valuable to know the `:h tabpagenr`, then you can switch to that tabpage with `:h tabnext {count}`. I don't know why I started talking about that, sorry.

Comment: It's ok, I appreciate all inputs.  By default, vim puts a number (as indicated in screenshot 3~/.vimrc, to show number of splits.  I didnt have any special settings, and its kinda hard to see so I was wondering if the color can be changed

Comment: I added an answer. That should have answered your questions. Did you see it? If it doesn't work, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember it uses `Title` highlight group.

PS, indeed for default tabline `Title` is used:

[image]